# How to make a discord bot leave a server from a command in another server?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

im currently developing a Discord .Py bot; and im wanting to to be able to force my bot to leave a server if the server owner is abusing the bot; now the whole issue i have is;

1) How would i go about doing this from another server? as in say Server1(my command post): This is the server where ALL admin/dev cmds are done... so say someone is abusing the bot in Server2(random server) i would like to type in Server1 !leave 'servername' it would say a message in the server "I have been requested to leave this server by the creator" and then leave...

2) is this even possible???

Thanks in advance for any help towards this project :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As `client.leave_server()` takes a `Server` as input, you will need to get that server first. Assuming you want to have a command that leaves a server based on the id that is given, this should do the trick:

```
toleave = client.get_server("id")
await client.leave_server(toleave)
```

where `id` is the ID of the server to leave.

Answer (score 5):

To build upon DismissedGuy [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48487670/9869598):

discord.py rewrite version:

```
to_leave = client.get_guild(id)
await to_leave.leave()
```

"await to_leave.leave()" Thanks to user [abccd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6622817/abccd)

Comment: Why not just `await to_leave.leave()`?

Comment: @abccd because to_leave was only defined when the guild was fetched.

Comment: @Theo abccd was refering to when my answer was a little more complex

Answer (score 1):

To make the bot leave from the server that the command was used from, use:

```py
await client.leave_server(message.server)
```

For rewrite:

```py
await message.server.leave()
```