# How can I make a command that makes my bot leave a specific server?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I want to use a command like `-svleave` and the name or id of the server, and the bot to leave that server as a result. I searched on google how to do it but I only got this post [How to make a discord bot leave a server from a command in another server?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48252035) and it doesn't show me how to implement it as a command like: `@client.command()` but I don't see how to add it as a command.

```
from discord.ext import commands
import discord.utils

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "-")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Ahri is Ready!')
    await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=discord.Game("cu pizda lui ma-ta"))
    

@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'Ping: {round(client.latency * 1000)}')

################################################################
#                          ADMIN                               #
################################################################

@client.command(pass_context=True) # Send Message As Bot
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def sudo(ctx, *, message):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    await ctx.send(message)

@client.command() # Clears Messages
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def clear(ctx, amount=5):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)

@client.command() # Kicks Members
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def kick(ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    await member.kick(reason=reason)
    await ctx.send(f"Kicked {member.mention}")

@client.command() # Bans Members
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def ban(ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    await member.ban(reason=reason)
    await ctx.send(f"Banned {member.mention}")

@client.command() # Unbans Members
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def unban(ctx, *, member):
    banned_users= await ctx.guild.bans()
    member_name, member_discriminator = member.split('#')

    for ban_entry in banned_users:
        user = ban_entry.user

        if (user.name, user.discriminator) == (member_name, member_discriminator):
            await ctx.guild.unban(user)
            await ctx.send(f"Unbanned {user.mention}")
            return

################################################################
#                          ROLES                               #
################################################################

role = "Newcomer"

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    rank = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name = role)
    await member.add_roles(rank)

@client.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def leaveguild(self, ctx, *, guild: discord.Guild):
    await guild.leave()
    await ctx.send(f"I've left {guild.name}!")
    

client.run("")
```

Comment: Welcome to stack**overflow** @SE. Have pity on us non-native speakers: Try to formulate excruciatingly unmistakably. Don't use non-trivial/common abbreviations, acronyms or tags like [idc](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=idc).

Answer (score 0):

The code below allows you to input either a name or an ID of a guild to leave it, and makes sure that you, the owner of the bot, is the one running the command.

You can read more [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.leave)

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

@client.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def leaveguild(ctx, *, guild: discord.Guild):
    await guild.leave()
    await ctx.send(f"I've left {guild.name}!")
```

Comment: i get this error: discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: guild is a required argument that is missing.

Comment: Yes, you need to provide input for the guild argument. So like `[p]leaveguild [guildname|guildid]` `[p]leaveguild MyGuild`

Comment: yes i type -leaveguild 719568406495625238 and it doesnt work and if i try to type the name (it has spaces between) it says   raise BadArgument('Converting to "{}" failed for parameter "{}".'.format(name, param.name)) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.BadArgument: Converting to "Guild" failed for parameter "guild".

Comment: I have edited my answer to allow server names with spaces, though the ID should work, what error do you get with the ID? (note the edit is an asterisk "*" between ctx and guild.)

Comment: discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: guild is a required argument that is missing. still this one and i typed the ID

Comment: Can you update your question to include an example of how you usually make commands please

Comment: I see now! Remove the `self` as I've done in my response, sorry for the issues! Let me know if this works.

Comment: man this is so complicated =))) now i get this without the self :   raise BadArgument('Converting to "{}" failed for parameter "{}".'.format(name, param.name)) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.BadArgument: Converting to "Guild" failed for parameter "guild".

Comment: What did you provide to it, are you sure it's a guild that the bot is in?

Comment: again, what did you provide it.

Comment: u mean the server id or what?